# presentModalViewController inside a UIButton subclass

Tags: ios, uibutton

Very new to iOS coding.  I'd like to be able to display a modal dialog from inside a UIButton subclass.   I've used `presentModalViewController` from inside a `UIViewController` before.  How would I grab a reference to a `UIViewController` from my subclassed UIButton?

Can I somehow discover it's parent?  Implement a protocol in the parent `UIViewController` that I can set as a delegate on my UIButton subclass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use any subclassed `UIButton` just as a normal `UIButton`. Setup an action that is triggered on the button which will call a method on the view controller. The view controller will deal with pushing the modal view controller.

Although there are ways in which you can find out the view controller from the button when it is attached to a view, this is a better approach.

Comment: When you say to setup an action for button push - is this setup done inside the view controller?  (this is making more sense)

Comment: Inside the view controller using `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`